# postgre - Finding rows that don't exist in t1 based on data in t2

Tags: postgresql

I have a data table `t1` that lists devices and `policy` objects defined on them, and a schema table `t2` that contains the master list of `policy` objects that should exist on devices. I am trying to write a query that will return a list of all policy's that are missing on devices.

`t1`:

| name | os | policy |
| --- | --- | --- |
| sw01 | ios | 1000M |
| sw01 | ios | 2G |
| sw02 | iosxr | 1G |
| sw02 | iosxr | 2G |

`t2`:

| os | policy |
| --- | --- |
| ios | 1G |
| ios | 2G |
| ios | 3G |
| iosxr | 1G |

Using the sample above, the query should return something like:

| name | policy_missing |
| --- | --- |
| sw01 | 1G |

I have tried a few different things, but have never written a query like this before, that keys of a row of values from one table to find what is missing on another. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Why is '1G' missing but not '3G'?

Comment: You're correct, 3G would be missing as well. Typo on my part.

Answer (score 1):

here you go

```
    create table t1 (name varchar(20), os varchar(10), policy varchar(10));
    create table t2 (os varchar(10), policy varchar(10));
    insert into t1 (name, os, policy) values ('sw01', 'ios', '1000M');
    insert into t1 (name, os, policy) values ('sw01', 'ios', '2G');
    insert into t1 (name, os, policy) values ('sw02', 'iosxr', '1G');
    insert into t1 (name, os, policy) values ('sw02', 'iosxr', '2G');
    
    insert into t2 (os, policy) values ('ios', '1G');
    insert into t2 (os, policy) values ('ios', '2G');
    insert into t2 (os, policy) values ('ios', '3G');
    insert into t2 (os, policy) values ('iosxr', '1G');
    
    select distinct aa.name, t2.policy from t2 
    join t1 aa on t2.os=aa.os 
    where t2.policy not in (select bb.policy from t1 bb where aa.name=bb.name)
```